# Live wallpaper: IllegalArgumenException on unlockCanvasAndPost when turned in landscape

Tags: android, canvas, live-wallpaper, illegalargumentexception

I'm developing a live wallpaper, and I have a problem that has been bugging me for a while. My live wallpaper crashes when it's turned into landscape and then back to portrait several times in a row. 
The LogCat shows the following error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>   at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Native >Method)
>   at com.android.internal.view.BaseSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(BaseSurfaceHolder.java:215)
>   at livewallpaper.LiveWallpaper$CatWallEngine.draw(LiveWallpaper.java:167)....

This is the code:

```
    public void draw() {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
        Canvas c = null;
        paint = new Paint();
        try {
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (c != null ) {
                //drawing code goes here
            }

        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }

        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateDisplay);
        if (mVisible) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateDisplay, 50);
        }
```

The line 167 is the holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c); line. 
I've read elsewhere that trying to unlock the canvas that is not locked might cause this error, but I've checked that and that's not the problem: canvas gets locked every time before trying to unlock it.

Comment: Try looking into surface holder callback .. I think you are not accounting for something during the orientation change which destroys everything. example; what if your your canvas is redrawn while you switch your view so the canvas is no longer valid and you try to remove, it will cause an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I added the try/catch block inside my 'finally' block, the live wallpaper stopped crashing. 
My 'finally' block looks like this now:

```
            try {
                if (c != null) {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: that means even if you don't call the code inside `finally` block, its still the same thing

Comment: The live wallpaper will be executed in the portrait mode mostly, and will most likely not be switched to landscape often enough to cause an exception (only few phones support live wallpapers in landscape anyway), so the `finally` block will be executed most of the time. I know that this only masks the problem, but I'm not seeing any consequences of doing so at this moment, and since I don't have any other solution, I'll just leave it like that.

Comment: Actually, when I think about it, it's not only masking the problem. The code will be skipped only when an invalid canvas is being unlocked, in which case we don't have to unlock it anyway. In other cases, that is - in most of the cases, the `finally` block will be executed normally.